# Read specific row of data from tsv with 100k+ lines, using standard libraries only

Tags: c++, csv, file-io

**Edit3** Final solution provided below.

I have a data file of the following structure (It is a Design Point Matrix for Simulation Analysis):

```
+----------+----------------------+-----------------+----------+----------+----------+-----------+-------------+
| ConfigID | k_StrategiesPerAgent | K_StrategySpace | l_Lambda | m_Memory | n_Agents | p_crowded |   s_Seed    |
+----------+----------------------+-----------------+----------+----------+----------+-----------+-------------+
|      0.0 |                  0.0 |             0.0 |      0.5 |     12.0 |     10.0 |       0.2 | 353756906.0 |
|      1.0 |                  0.0 |             0.2 |      0.5 |     12.0 |     10.0 |       0.2 | 923055597.0 |
|      2.0 |                  0.0 |             0.4 |      0.5 |     12.0 |     10.0 |       0.2 | 616881203.0 |
+----------+----------------------+-----------------+----------+----------+----------+-----------+-------------+
```

The file **"DPM.tsv"** is tab-separated and contains no spaces or free lines, etc., i.e.:

```
ConfigID    k_StrategiesPerAgent    K_StrategySpace l_Lambda    m_Memory    n_Agents    p_crowded   s_Seed
0.0 0.0 0.0 0.5 12.0    10.0    0.2 353756906.0
1.0 0.0 0.2 0.5 12.0    10.0    0.2 923055597.0
2.0 0.0 0.4 0.5 12.0    10.0    0.2 616881203.0
```

It may contain over 100k rows and also a large number of columns. The first column is a unique Identifier (Integer, [**0**,...]) which I would like to use in order to access the parameter values associated with it. In general, the numbering of "ConfigID" should be consequtive. I do not know the number of columns in advance.

I am searching for a function that will read in the header into a string vector and the according data, corresponding to the key, into a double vector (same sorting). This should be done without any special libraries as I would not know how to link them... Also I would appreciate a very simple structure that does work without a class/template etc. Something like

```
vector<string> Labels; //Hold the parameter labels
vector<double> Parameters; //Hold the parameter values
bool readPars(char * FilePath, int ConfigID); //load the label and value
                                            //return [false] on error, else [true]
```

Small Follow-Up: I will then want to access the data in the vectors through a loop, passing the values to some macro from the "language" I am using for my simulations ([laboratory for simulation development](https://github.com/marcov64/Lsd)). Therefore I will also want to "turn" the string into a char. This can then be done via adding ".c_str()" to the string, correct? e.g:

```
for (int i=0;i<Labels.size();i++){
  const char * lab = Labels[i].c_str();
  double par = Parameters[i];
  LSD_MACRO(lab,par)//do something
}
```

It is fine that the ConfigID is also part of the Labels[] and Parameters[]

Given my lack of programming experience my past way of "solving" this was to write a python script that hard-codes an array holding ALL the data, which I then included via #include ... but there are limitations to such a procedure.

Many thanks! -Frederik

---

### Solution: Following Jonathan Mee's answer and loading everything.

```
using namespace std;
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main()
{ 
  const char * DPM_File = "DPM.tsv";
  cout << DPM_File <<  endl; 
  ifstream  fileP(DPM_File); //Read File in tsv format, with header-line

  //read the header
  string label;
  getline(fileP, label, '\n'); 
  //create a string vector with the header
  istringstream gccNeedsThisOnASeperateLine{ label };                                   
  const vector<string> Labels{ istream_iterator<string>{ gccNeedsThisOnASeperateLine }, istream_iterator<string>{} };         

  //Read the remainer and parse it to a 2d vector of doubles
  vector<vector<double>> Parameters;
  do {
        vector<double> input(Labels.size());
        for(int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++){ 
        fileP >> input[i];
      }
      if(!fileP.fail()) //control for empty line at end of file
         Parameters.push_back(input);     
    } while(fileP.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n'));

  //Test:

  for (int i=0;i<Labels.size();i++){    
    cout << Labels[i] << "\t" << Parameters[0][i]  << endl;
  }
  cout << endl;

  for (int i=0;i<Labels.size();i++){    
    cout << Labels[i] << "\t" << Parameters[5][i]  << endl;
  }
  cout << endl;

  int sssize = Parameters.size();
  cout << "The sssize is" << sssize << endl;
  for (int i=0;i<Labels.size();i++){    
    cout << Labels[i] << "\t" << Parameters[sssize-1][i]  << endl;
  }
  cout << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you actually experienced crashes by out of memory? If not, I'd recommend to read all of the content of the file into the memory. The program will be the simplest, and will run the fastest because the file is read only once. Note that a file with 100k+ of lines with 1kB per line is still less than 1GB; it depends on circumstances but I guess your memory has enough space for that.

Comment: Hi, I had problems when I "hard-coded" it, like:

    double array[100000][20] = { { ...} , {....} , ....};

And I would like to have a somewhat "cleaner" version. But I will try reading everything in "on the run", although even there I do not completely understand how to (but there are answers to such a problem, I have read and will read now)

Comment: There are two kinds of memory, the stack and the heap. "Hard-coded" arrays are allocated on the stack, which is very fast but much smaller than the heap. The heap is used by the `new`, which is used internally by the classes such as `std::vector<double>`, `std::string`, etc. The idiomatic way in C++ to load a bunch of data from file(s) is to use `std::ifstream` to read into objects of such classes.

Comment: Many thanks Ohashi, that explains the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's talk about your data structures:

1. The labels must be held separately from a structure containing your `double`s otherwise you'll end up with *n*-copies of the same labels. So we'll put the labels in the container `vector<string> Labels`
2. If your key column is contiguous starting at 1 simply place your doubles in a `vector<vector<double>> Parameters` and the index will serve as the zero-based key, if not you'll need to use a `map<int, vector<double>> Parameters`, since it's simpler we'll assume that the numbers are contiguous and use `vector<vector<double>> Parameters`

Given that you've successfully opened the file into `ifstream fileP` you can get your `Labels` like this:

```
string label;

getline(fileP, label, '\n');   

const vector<string> Labels{ istream_iterator<string>{ istringstream{ label } }, istream_iterator<string>{} };
```

Thought there are fancier methods, we can simply use a nested `for`-loop to extract `vector<vector<double>> Parameters`:

```
while(fileP.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\t')) {
    vector<double> input(size(Labels) - 1);

    for(int i = 0; i < size(input) && fileP >> input[i]; ++i);
    Parameters.push_back(input);
}
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://ideone.com/utYHGC)

Comment: Ok, I managed to include all I need for a MWE

    using namespace std;
    #include <fstream>
    #include <string>
    #include <vector>

But I get an error: test.cpp:36:30: warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11

I guess I do not have c++11 ;)

Comment: @Frederik Sounds positive, but I'm not certain what an MWE is.

Comment: I don't know what version of gcc you have but you should probably be using the: -std=c++14 or -std=c++17 flag in this day and age.

Comment: MWE = Minimum Working Example.
Ok, I added the flag and it works with cygwin's g++. Learned something.
Still, I get warnings. `using namespace std;
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{  
  ifstream  fileP("DPM.tsv"); 
  string label;
  getline(fileP, label, '\n'); 
  cout << label; //Works!
  const vector<string> Labels{ istream_iterator<string>{ istringstream{ label } }, istream_iterator<string>{} };
  return 0;
}`

Comment: Warning: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'std::istream_iterator<std::basic_string<char> >::istream_type& {aka std::basic_istream<char>&}' from an rvalue of type 'std::basic_istream<char>

Comment: I just found I did not get the "live example". Sorry for that, this is my first Q raised here... there it is different and seems to work.

Comment: How may I change it such that the ConfigID is also present (simply as double)? Otherwise it is working and reads in everything.

Comment: @Frederik I believe that your question is addressed in **2**. Say you want to access the `double`s on the line identified by 13, you'd do `Parameters[13]` which would return you a `vector<double>` of the `double`s read on that line. Now as mentioned in **2** the only reason that you'd want to do this would be if your indexing isn't contiguous. You didn't say that was the case, so perhaps it would be preferable that you explain what you're attempting to do and perhaps I can assist.

Comment: It is contiguous, it is only I want to be able to "also" extract the first column (treat ConfigID as Parameter, say). I do not want to treat it as key explicitly. One reason is I might end-up splitting the DPM, or adding additional Configurations in a separate file later. Also, I save the results from the simulation by referring to the config ID and hence save it with the results (and make it error-safe). I tried to change the code such that each row in the vector Parameters is of size `Labels.size()` but in short did not succeed.

Comment: Hmm... I tried to put my code to ideone, but found then that using the "mock" file `ifstream  fileP( "ConfigID\tLabel1\tLabel2\tLabel3\n1\t.3\t.3\t10.0\n2\t.2\t.2e-3\t0.1n3\t.4\t.2\t9.9" );` is not the same as using a "real" file for input. Anyway, here is my try: [link](http://ideone.com/FDLXrS)[link]

Comment: @Frederik In the general case I would advise against "splitting up the `vector`" in favor of using offsets. But since I don't know your code, here's how I'd populate a map: `for(int key; fileP >> key;) { vector<double> input; for(int i = 0; i < input.size() && fileP >> input[i]; ++i); Parameters[key] = input; }` Again this smells like bad design so I'm not adding it into the main answer.

Comment: @Johnatan I edited the code section in the Q and also added a screen-shot from the error. Perhaps that is more clear...